# Tricky query to find coordinates from a category and within radius

Tags: mysql, coordinates

I'm having trouble coming up with a quite complicated query involving Items, Categories, and Users. All that must come together so the User who has selected a given Category to monitor are notified when new Items are inserted within a radius.

I already have this query, to calculate the distance between a coordinate and other Items.

```
SELECT i.id, ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians(-22.915037) ) * cos( radians( lat ) ) *
cos( radians( lng ) - radians(-43.207169) ) + sin( radians(-22.915037) )  *sin(radians(lat)) ) )*1.6 AS distance
FROM user u, item i
WHERE u.id = i.user_id
)
```

But I'm having trouble putting it all togehter in one SQL statement. Let me explain a little more. It's a little tricky.

The coordinates (lat, long) are in the Users table. Users have Items, and Items are of a given Category. There is a table (lets call it Monitor) that a user selects a Category and a radius (1, 5, 10, 50km, etc).

And everytime a new Item is inserted I put it on a separate table (lets call it NewItems), so I can process it separately.

What I want is, every time a certain process is executed, get all the Items in NewItems, and check if they match the Categories watched for in Monitor, and fall within the radius configured, so I can notify each user who has a Monitor in that category and radius.

In the end, what I need is just a resultset (or table) with ItemID and UserID, so I can email each user telling them a new Item was inserted in the category and radius they were monitoring.

A bit more detail on my tables (just enough to understand how the query should be built).

`Users: id, lat, lng`

`Item: id, user_id, category_id`

`Category: id, name`

`Monitor: category_id, user_id, radius`

`NewItems: item_id, flag_notified`

Answer (score 0):

What about something like this?

```
SELECT DISTINCT u.id, n.id
FROM Users u
JOIN Monitor m
  on u.user_id = m.owning_user_id
JOIN NewItems n
  on n.category_id = m.category_id
 and ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians(u.lat) ) * cos( radians( n.lat ) ) * cos( radians( n.lng ) - radians(u.lng) ) + sin( radians(u.lat) )  *sin(radians(n.lat)) ) )*1.6 < m.radius_in_km
```

This assumes that the location belongs to the user and that a monitor is a combination of category and radius.

If you need something that performs better, a spatial index might eliminate some of the table scanning this will do.

Comment: Thanks for the effort but the NewItems table doesn't have coordinates (it only has Item_id) and you have `n.lat` and `n.long` there. This is one of the main problems I'm having. Perhaps a different approach to calculate the radius?

Comment: I added the table details to help understand the "trickyness" of the problem. :)

Comment: How do you know where the `NewItems` are?  If you have no idea, it's not just tricky: it's impossible.  You can't test the distance between two locations if you only know one of them.

Comment: NewItems are Items, and they belong to Users. I finally got the query working, I just needed to JOIN with Users two times (one for Item Owner and the other for Monitoring User.